# Is the `:as` binding useful only when the argument to a function is a temporary?

Tags: data-binding, functional-programming, clojure, pattern-matching, destructuring

The first usage of `:as` shown in [*Clojure Programming*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/clojure-programming/9781449310387/) is the following

```clj
(let [[x _ z :as original-vector] v]
  (conj original-vector (+ x z)))
;= [42 foo 99.2 [5 12] 141.2]
```

However, by experimenting a bit on https://rextester.com/l/clojure_online_compiler, I see that `v` is visible in the body of `let`, so I can just skip the `:as` destructuring and use `v` instead of `original-vector`, and the result is the same

```clj
(let [[x _ z] v]
  (conj v (+ x z)))
;= [42 foo 99.2 [5 12] 141.2]
```

This is clearly not doable if I have a more complex expression instead of `v` (in C++ I'd say a *temporary*/*rvalue*, whereas `v` would be an *lvalue*).

So my question is: is the `:as` syntax useful only when we destructure a temporary, whereas it is totally redundant when we destructure a named entity? I mean in the example above it seems the only difference in using `:as` is that we refer to `v` via another name, but I don't see how this can be advantageous in any way...

---

The example assumes

```clj
(def v [42 "foo" 99.2 [5 12]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that the `:as` destructuring technique can be redundant. However, `:as` in a destructuring form is almost always used with a function's argument vector, rather than with a `let` form:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn myfun
  [[x _ z :as original-vector]]
  (conj original-vector (+ x z)))

(dotest
  (is= [1 2 3 4]
    (myfun [1 2 3])))
```

However, it is well worth noting that the full power of destructuring
is available for both function arguments and `let` forms.

---

The example is built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Comment: I would say it is used reasonably often in a `let` form, as well. The only place it is (of course!) rarely used is to destructure a named value, because why would you give a value a name and then later destructure it, rather than doing both at once. e.g., `(let [[x y :as coords] (foo)] ...)` instead of `(let [coords (foo) [x y] coords])`.